# Magnetism in the original Cavendish Experiment (1798)

Tags: geomagnetism

This is what Henry Cavendish writes on page 490 [here](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstl.1798.0022)

> My next trials were, to see whether this effect was owing to
> magnetism. Now, as it happened, the case in which the arm was
> inclosed, was placed nearly parallel to the magnetic east and west,
> and therefore, if there was any thing magnetic in the balls and
> weights, the balls would acquire polarity from the earth; and the
> weights also, after having remained some time, either in the positive
> or negative position, would acquire polarity in the same direction,
> and would attract the balls; but, when the weights were moved to the
> contrary position, that pole which before pointed to the north, would
> point to south, and would repel the ball it was approached to: but
> yet, as repelling one ball towards the south has the same effect on
> the arm as attracting the other towards the north, this would have no
> effect on the position of the arm. After some time, however, the poles
> of the weight would be reversed, and would begin to attract the balls,
> and would therefore produce the same kind of effect as was actually
> observed.

[…]

> We may be sure, therefore, that the effect in question could not be
> produced by magnetism in the weights; for, if it was, turning them
> half round on their axes, would immediately have changed their
> magnetic attraction into repulsion, and have produced a motion in the
> arm.

Why does Cavendish say “...*magnetic* east and west”? Isn’t magnetism north and south?

And why would a lead weight “acquire polarity” from earth? I understand this to mean that, the sphere would acquire south and north poles and become attractive as a magnet.

I’m not clear what is going on here. Can you explain Cavendish’s concerns? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a better fits for [hsm.se]

Comment: I'm asking about polarization of lead. Can you make lead magnetic? This should be on topic for physics, I believe. Can a lead sphere acquire polarity from terrestrial magnetism?

Answer (score 4):

*Why does Cavendish say “...magnetic east and west”? Isn’t magnetism north and south?*.

A compass defines magnetic north and south and orthogonal to that line is the magnetic east-west direction.
Cavendish’s balls and the attaching arm were therefore perpendicular to the Earth’s magnetic field.
He then reasoned that any effect due to the Earth’s magnetic field would be equal on the two balls and thus cancel out.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding polarization. Why or how lead which is not magnetic acquire polarization?

Comment: @zeynel It was more a case of, **if** the balls were magnetised would that have an effect on the results.

Comment: Ok, disregarding the Cavendish experiment, can you magnetize lead? In this video copper is magnetized but lead is not. https://youtu.be/VEIYXomRdLY

Comment: A lovely answer to your question is in [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/diamagnetic-vs-paramagnetic).